# Incomplete json structure - no count/next/previous/results field

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

like many times before, im trying to send data from my Django backend to my Ionic mobile app.

This time, however, for some reason, the .jsons im parsing are coming out incomplete.

A complete .json:

```
{"count":1,"next":null,"previous":null,"results":[{"codigo":"qwe","area":"ewq","especies":[],"id":1}]}
```

My incomplete .json:

```
[{"nome_ficheiro":"1520529086252.jpg","id":26,"especie":"Ameijoa Branca","zona":"L6","data":"09/06/2018"}]
```

IONIC is struggling with identifying what I'm parsing as a .json, which makes sense since there is no "results" field.

Here are the relevant snippets of my django code:

Views.py (both Views are doing the same thing! This is just me trying out different approaches!)

```
class resultUploadViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request, nome_ficheiro):
        queryset    = labelResult.objects.all()
        nome        = nome_ficheiro
        answer      = queryset.filter(nome_ficheiro=nome)
        serializer  = resultSerializer(answer, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

class resultUploadView(APIView):
    serializer_class = resultSerializer

    def get(self, request, nome_ficheiro):
        queryset    = labelResult.objects.all()
        nome        = nome_ficheiro
        answer      = queryset.filter(nome_ficheiro=nome)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(answer, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Models.py

```
class labelResult(models.Model):
    nome_ficheiro   = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    especie         = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    zona            = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    data            = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'results/(?P<nome_ficheiro>.+)/$', resultUploadViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})),
url(r'results1/(?P<nome_ficheiro>.+)/$', resultUploadView.as_view())]
```

Serializers.py

```
class resultSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model =  labelResult
    fields = ('nome_ficheiro','id','especie','zona', 'data')
```

Any idea why my .jsons are coming out incomplete?

Answer (score 1):

you should use `ListAPIView` so the pagination is applied.
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview

more on pagination you can find here:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/